# How do I properly align my button inputs to the right at the bottom of a form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following extension of the usual button that VS 2013 scaffolds at the bottom of a form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-danger" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-warning" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This group of elements aligns to the left, i.e. the '**Reset**' button's left edge aligns with the left edge of the 'PhoneNumber' input. I would like the right edge of the '**Cancel**' button to align with the right edge of the 'PhoneNumber' field. How do I do this?

Comment: If its possible to provide jsfiddle then it will be great. Thanx

Comment: What will a jsfiddle add? This is strictly an alignment issue and all the code for that, the 2nd `form-group` is all that matters, and it has nearly zero behavior. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.text-right` on the parent container which has the property `text-align: right`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">Phone number</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="form-control">Phone Number</div>
    <div class="text-danger">Validation text</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    <div class="text-right">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-danger" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
      <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-warning" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `pull-right` to each button to align right and reverse their order:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 btn-group">
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" />

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That pulls them all the way to the right of the whole page, not just the form.

Comment: @ProfK that's the best you can do with bootstrap default classes. If you want the buttons align with the right side of your input field you have to stretch you input field all the way to the right side of your container.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pull-right class instead of col-md-offset-2. In the same col-md-10 use the pull-right class to float the element on the right of the div.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">Phone number</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="form-control">Phone Number</div>
    <div class="text-danger">Validation text</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="pull-right col-md-10">
   
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-danger" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
      <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-warning" />
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12 pull-right btn-group">
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" />

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

```
<input type="submit" style="left-margin: 50px"/>
```

Use this. You can set it also using above defined class, but another way is to write style with margin right 0 pixel.